# How To Highlight Specific Text Within A Cell Based On Other Text using Python?

Tags: python, excel, conditional-statements

In my excel file two columns are there.Column A has paragraph and column B has words.my requirement is what are words present in column B should be highlighted in column A.like if pest in column B.How many pest are there in column A first row should be highlighted.As sure in second row sure should be highlighted.I have written code but it is highlighting whole lines[image]

my code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
from openpyxl.styles import colors
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Color
import pandas as pd
ft = Font(color=colors.GREEN, bold=True)
wb = load_workbook('sample_sentence.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
a1 = ws['A']
for a in a1:
    a2 = a
for cell1 in ws['A']:
   for cell in ws['B']:
      if cell.value.lower() in cell1.value.lower():
         a2.font = ft
         wb.save('sample_sentence.xlsx')
```

my requirement is in first A1 column pest should be highlighted second A2 column sure should be highlighted

Answer (score 0):

In VBA this could be solved as:

```
Function Highlight(r As Range, t As String) As String
    Dim Search As Range
    Dim SearchIn As String
    Dim Position As Integer
    Dim Color As Long
    Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

    SearchIn = r.Text
    Position = InStr(1, SearchIn, t, vbTextCompare)
    r.Characters(Start:=Position, Length:=Len(t)).Font.Color = Color

    Highlight = t
End Function
```

In your call use: `=Highlight(A1,"pest")`   will turn the word "pest" into a red color.

Comment: Can Help out in python